# How can I remove the previous Buttons after clicking on another one?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm developing a project that requires a great amount of buttons. But I need for some button to remove previous ones. For example, when I click on the first button in stage 1, I want it to remove itself and the other one on stage 1, while the ones in stage 2 show up. I'm trying this apart from my actual project because I already tried with queues, lists and tuples.

How can I do this? Looks pretty simple, but it's been really complicated achieving this. The code compiles, when I click a button, the others show up, but I can't remove them or make them not visible. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

```
//Creates buttons on stage one

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Location = new Point(20, 30 * i + 10);
            button.Visible = true;
            button.Text = "stage1";

            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick2);
                    break;
            }

            this.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }

    void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // First Button Clicked
        // Creates buttons on stage 2

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Location = new Point(200, 30 * i + 10);
            button.Visible = true;
            button.Text = "stage2";

            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick3);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick4);
                    break;
            }
            this.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
    void ButtonClick2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Second Button Clicked
    }

    void ButtonClick3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Third Button Clicked
    }

    void ButtonClick4(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fourth Button Clicked
    }
```

[image: Visual Representation of the buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give your buttons a unique name:

```
button.Name = "button1";
```

Then you can remove them later:

```
this.Controls.Remove((Button)Controls["button1"]);
```